# Does validate() method have a limit on errors it can redirect back in Laravel 6?

Tags: validation, laravel-6, laravel-validation

Does the `validate()` method have a limit on errors that it can redirect back to Laravel? Below is my validation method. It is not working with this many fields. However, if I comment out some fields than it starts working. I suspected that some fields might contain syntax error but that is not the case since I checked all of them separately. Can anyone point me to the problem?

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'first_name' => 'bail|required|max:35|regex:^[a-zA-Z]+$',
    'middle_name' => 'bail|nullable|max:35|regex:^[a-zA-Z]+$',
    'last_name' => 'bail|required|max:35|regex:^[a-zA-Z]+$',
    'user_name' => 'bail|required|max:70|regex:^[a-zA-Z\s]*$',
    'company_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:345|unique:users',
    'password' => 'bail|required|min:8|max:255|regex:^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$',
    'cnic' => 'bail|required|max:15|regex:\d{5}-\d{7}-\d',
    'nationality' => 'bail|required|max:74|regex:^[a-zA-Z\s]*$',
    'date' => 'bail|required|date',
    'gender' => 'bail|required',
    'marital_status' => 'bail|required',
    'religion' => 'bail|required',
    'current_address' => 'bail|required|max:255',
    'permanant_address' => 'bail|required|max:255',
    'personal_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:345|unique:users',
    'primary_phone' => 'bail|required|max:15|regex:^(\+923)\d{9}$',
    'secondary_phone' => 'bail|required|max:15|regex:^(\+923)\d{9}$',
    'company_skype' => 'required',
    'personal_skype' => 'nullable',
    'linked_in' => 'bail|nullable|max:2000|url',
    'github_link' => 'bail|nullable|max:2000|url',
    'stackoverflow_link' => 'bail|nullable|max:2000|url',
    'full_name' => 'bail|required|max:75|regex:^[a-zA-Z\s]*$',
    'relation_name' => 'bail|required|max:255|regex:^[a-zA-Z\s]*$',
    'branch' => 'required',
    'phone_number' => 'bail|required|max:15|regex:^(\+923)\d{9}$',
    'department' => 'required',
    'designation' => 'required',
    'level' => 'required',
    'experience' => 'bail|required|max:4',
    'join_date' => 'bail|required|date',
    'account_status' => 'required'
]);
```

I am actually dumping the errors using var_dump().
This is what i am getting when i comment most of the key/value pairs in my array which passed to the validate method.

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#245 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(1) { ["default"]=> object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#246 (2) { ["messages":protected]=> array(10) { ["first_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "The first name field is required." } ["last_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "The last name field is required." } ["user_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "The user name field is required." } ["company_email"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "The company email field is required." } ["password"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "The password field is required." } ["cnic"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "The cnic field is required." } ["nationality"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(34) "The nationality field is required." } ["personal_email"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(37) "The personal email field is required." } ["primary_phone"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "The primary phone field is required." } ["secondary_phone"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(38) "The secondary phone field is required." } } ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message" } } }
```

When i uncomment all of the keys of array i am passing to the validate array this is what i get:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#247 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

I also tried Validate::make method but the behavior was still the same and i am not able to resolve the issue.

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:35|regex:^[a-zA-Z]+$',
            'middle_name' => 'nullable|max:35|regex:^[a-zA-Z]+$',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:35|regex:^[a-zA-Z]+$',
            'user_name' => 'required|max:70|regex:^[a-zA-Z\s]*$',
            'company_email' => 'required|email|max:345|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255|regex:^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$',
            'cnic' => 'required|max:15|regex:\d{5}-\d{7}-\d',
            'nationality' => 'required|max:74|regex:^[a-zA-Z\s]*$',
            // 'date' => 'required|date',
            // 'gender' => 'required',
            // 'marital_status' => 'required',
            // 'profile_picture' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2000000',
            'personal_email' => 'bail|required|email|max:345|unique:users',
            'primary_phone' => 'bail|required|max:15|regex:^(\+923)\d{9}$',
            'secondary_phone' => 'bail|required|max:15|regex:^(\+923)\d{9}$',

            // 'current_address' => 'required|max:255',
            'permanant_address' => 'required|max:255',
            // 'religion' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/user/create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

My Laravel.logs file doesnot have any error too.

Comment: `It is not working` - what does this mean **exactly**?  Describe exactly what you see, and what you expected.  Anything in your logs?

Comment: It redirects to the same page.

Comment: which means its aware of failed validation however it doesnot return back the errors array. The error array is empty.

Comment: I expected the errors array to have errors when i am purposely missing fields.

Comment: How are you checking `errors` array? Can you show?

Comment: by dumping $errors using var_dump using var_dump

Comment: Try removing `bail` from all valildations and try.

Comment: that didnot worked

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem.
maybe this is solution

.env

```html
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```